# How to calculate throughput in a Jmeter test plan

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter test plan using which I am running 10 - 500 threads. Each thread submits a job. I am basically collecting results like 10 jobs and measure the latency of each job. I know summary report gives a nice report on throughput, but that report is not suitable for my test because my test plan has 1 POST plus 11 GET calls in it and the summary report gives throughout of each those calls. But I need to measure throughput for each 10 threads, 50 and 100 threads respectively. Could someone let me know how should I go this in JMeter or do I have to calculate manually? Note: I'm allowing 10sec ramp up time for 10 threads.

Comment: there are many meanings to "throughput", so what exactly are you trying to measure? give an example

Comment: I'm trying to measure no. of request / per unit of time? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are right: summary report gives you throughput for each call. To measure multiple calls at once, add them under [Transaction controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller). For example, say you want to measure overall throughput of all GETs at once, put them all under Transaction controller, but not the POST request, so summary graph will contain measurement for each of the GET requests, plus separate line which includes all of them at once.

Another (non-interactive) option is to [save results as CSV file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Sample_Result_Save_Configuration), including label and latency, and calculate throughput using Excel (or awk) from the file.

To measure for different number of users, you need to run test multiple times with that number of concurrent threads/users.

Comment: In the csv file, we can calculate throughput using: NoOfSamples/(EndTime-StartTime). However, what do the following calculation gives us: 1) NoOfSamples/TotalElapsedTime; 1) NoOfSamples/AvgElapsedTime

Comment: @variable comments are not the best place for new questions. Create a new question instead and someone will answer.